# All Minecraft target selector arguments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using any minecraft command that requires a entity to run (like `/tp` `/testfor` and etc) requires a entity piece, you can do it with players using the playername, and you can do with `@e`, `@r`, `@p` and `@a`, providing arguments or not.  That is my question: **What are all Minecraft selector arguments (in 1.8)** The ones I currently know are score_scorename=value, score_scorename_min=value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Via the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors)

#### Present in 1.8

1. `x` = X coordinate of search origin
2. `y` = Y coordinate of search origin
3. `z` = Z coordinate of search origin
4. `r` = radius maximum in blocks
5. `rm` = radius minimum in blocks
6. `m` = gamemode (0: survival, 1: creative, 2: adventure, 3: spectator)
7. `score_[name]` = score maximum
8. `score_[name]_min` = score minimum
9. `c` = maximum targets (not minimum, of which there is none)
10. `l` = level maximum
11. `lm` = level minimum
12. `team` = scoreboard team name
13. `name` = player username or entity CustomName (translated default name if no CustomName)
14. `dx` = number of blocks in the X direction to search in
15. `dy` = number of blocks in the Y direction to search in
16. `dz` = number of blocks in the Z direction to search in
17. `rx` = vertical rotation maximum
18. `rxm` = vertical rotation minimum
19. `ry` = horizontal rotation maximum
20. `rym` = horizontal rotation minimum
21. `type` = [entity ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values/Entity_IDs) (only available for `@r` and `@e`)

#### Added in 1.9

1. `tag` = scoreboard "tag" stored on the target (via `Tags` list, modifiable with `/scoreboard players tag <target> <add|remove> <tagname> {dataTags}`)